# Add icons and marker on Google Map Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

Is there anyway to add Popup view (car icon,duration and distance) like the image below in android ?I have used marker to indicate locations .When user click location , I would like to show Popup view with icons,duration,distance.

```
// Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

// Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
markerOptions.position(point);
markerOptions.title(clientName);

if(bitmap != null)
{ markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));}
else{
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
}

// Adding marker on the Google Map
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

[image]

Comment: @peter could manage to add and icon and title.

Answer (score 0):

This page explains the Marker object from Google Maps Android API.
I think there is some usefull info for you in there. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Hope this will put you on track:

```
private MapFragment mMapFragment;
//(in my case, MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener)
Marker marker =  mMapFragment.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(yourObject.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(yourObject.getLongitude())))
                            .title(yourObject.getName())
                            .snippet(yourObject.getAddress())
                            .data(yourObject.getWhatever()), yourObject);
            mAddedObjectsIds.put(yourObject.getId(),marker);
```

Comment: thanks I have found useful information .What I need to use is infowindows .https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#introduction

Comment: .data(yourObject.getWhatever()), yourObject); CAN NOT RESOLVE METHOD data(string,string)